# Removing an OpenVPN Client Cert

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I've added an OpenVPN client using the OpenVPN's /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key-pass script. However, I entered a typo on the person's name field, so I'd like to regenerate it. However, when I re-ran the script, it seemed to run correctly until the end, when it terminated with the error:

```
failed to update database
TXT_DB error number 2
```

Googling shows this error is rarely encountered, but in one [reported case](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=502&user=guest&pass=guest), a suggested solution was to run `openssl ca -revoke <username>.crt`.

However, when I try this, I get:

```
Using configuration from /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
Error opening CA private key /etc/pki/CA/private/cakey.pem
1403244616130376:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:392:fopen('/etc/pki/CA/private/cakey.pem','r')
1403244616130376:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:394:
unable to load CA private key
```

So now I'm trying to simply remove my previous crt and start over. How do I do this? I tried manually deleting the *.crt, *.csr, and *.key files generated, but re-running build-key-pass gives me the same db error. What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it on CRL list and create new cert.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm new to OpenVPN.

Comment: Check this http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#revoke

Comment: Like I said, I already deleted the crt, csr, and key files, so running revoke-full fails, because it needs these files.

Comment: Well, I missed that, can't you just go through easy-rsa process again? It should work ...

Comment: If you don't want to clean all: To clean just one certificate delete crt, csr, key, BUT also find it in the index.txt, remove it there and remove the pem file as indicated in the index. After that you can add a new cert with the same name.